# How to remove syntax error executing any .BAT file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

So I am a bit stuck right now as everytime I try to execute a .bat file in PowerShell. I get the following error:

`"&" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.`

Which roughly translates to `"&" cannot be used syntactically here.`. The problem is now that I do not know where this syntax error is coming from. A couple of days ago everything was fine, the only change I did to my system was reinstalling conda.

I get this output, if I try to execute any .bat file. Also when I try to call `cmd` I get this error, but the output will first print:

`Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052] (c) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.`

I know this a bit of a general problem description, but I honestly do not know where to start searching for a solution.

Comment: Can you share any code that you are using that might help us troubleshoot? There isn't enough information here to know what could be causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I could find the problem myself. My conda installation added an Autorun in the Registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor. Somewhere in the bat files used by conda there is a syntax error. Have not yet found where it is specifically, but removing the Autorun also removed the error.

Comment: Removing the entry from your registry was the appropriate thing to do. You should never have an autorun entry, anything which adds it, should be uninstalled, and never used again. _The developers are obviously clueless fools, with no idea or regard for your system_.